# MySQL query help wanted

Tags: mysql

I'm relatively new to MySQL, and it's possible that what I want may not be possible to achieve with one single query. I have the following table structure:

```
name | value1 | value2
```

I have several records where the names are the same but different values. What I would like to do is to select distinct names, but their values should be added. Here's an example:

```
john | 1 | 2
jane | 6 | 3
mark | 2 | 5
mark | 3 | 1
```

So the query (if possible) would return

```
john | 1 | 2
jane | 6 | 3
mark | 5 | 6
```

Comment: I would recommend purchasing an "Intro to SQL" type book. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982/looking-for-a-good-book-to-learn-sql) for some suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can using [group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).

Like

```
select name , sum(value1) as sum1, sum(value2) as sum2 from mytable group by name
```

Answer (score 2):

You use group by with agregating functions.

```
SELECT name, sum(value1) as total1,sum(value2) as total2 FROM mytable GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, sum(value1) as column1 ,sum(value2) as column2 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY name
```

I recommend to learn a few [lessons on MySQL](http://mysql-tools.com/mysql-lessons.html).
Me as a beginner it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT name, SUM(value1) as v1, SUM(value2) as v2 FROM table GROUP BY name";
```